# Categorical Schur's Lemma

Tags: kt.k-theory-and-homology, ct.category-theory, knot-theory

In attempt to prove (and compute) a formula for the dimensions of the HOMFLY homology
of the (p,q)-torus knot one could try to follow original proof by Jones of a formula for 
HOMFLY  polynomial of the torus knot. One of the key moments of the Jones proof
is Schur-Weyl duality and Schur's Lemma. Then the question:

What is a categorical analogues of the Schur's Lemma and Schur-Weyl duality.
In  general what are the obstacles for finding formula for the HOMLFLY homology
of the (p,q)-torus knot. 
Any refs and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

One categorical analogue of Schur's lemma is the definition of a [simple object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simple+object) in, say, an abelian category.  This is essentially an object $V$ for which a generalization of Schur's lemma holds.  In particular, all morphisms $f \colon V \to V$ are either isomorphisms or equal zero.

If the category is enriched over vector spaces over some field $k$, it follows that the vector space $\mathrm{hom}(V,V)$ becomes a division algebra over $k$.   If $k$ is algebraically complete, it then follows that $\mathrm{hom}(V,V) \cong k$.